# RFID/NFC transponder with current delivered via wire

Tags: pcb, antenna, rfid, pcb-antenna, nfc

I'm sure everybody here knows how RFID transponder works, reflecting radio waves and receiving them at the source.

[image]

I'm looking for the same concept, but instead of the input to the transponder being radio waves, I'd like to apply a current directly and have an antenna listening for it.

I'm seeing lots of [very small RFID/NFC transponders](https://core-electronics.com.au/micro-nfc-rfid-transponder-ntag203-13-56mhz.html), but can't seem to find wired equivalents. It is a transponder I am after yes? I'm looking for something about 10x10mm with a range of 1ft.

Thank you

Comment: i think that RFID transponers do more than just reflect radio waves

Comment: Hi there, refer to my added image. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are seeking. You want the tag/transponder to run of an external supply?

Comment: Exactly! So when I supply a voltage to the transponder, a nearby antenna (30cm away) can detect it.

Comment: Sounds very much like an XY problem. Why do you need a transponder system to do what you want rather than some optical or acoustic detection method?

Comment: Hi Andy, apologies my knowledge is rather lacking. Could you elaborate on optical/acoustic signals which can have a current delivered to them and be picked up by a receiver? Thanks!

Comment: I should add, what I want is a single receiver that listens to a number of different transmitters, with each transmitter being activated via a wire/switch. Each transmitter needs to be smaller than 10x10mm